# How many parametrisations are needed to cover a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, spheres, parametrization

I have seen that a sphere can be covered with 6 parametrisations, but is it possible to totally cover a sphere with less parametrisations/charts?

Comment: the number of needed charts for a sphere from which you removed some convex part  is only $1$. with the Riemann sphere, you can see removing only a point is enough for the sphere become homomorphic to a plane

Comment: a question : what about the hyper-sphere in dimension $3,4,5,\ldots$ ? and the hyper-torus ? (I don't know the answer)

Comment: @user1952009 The hyper-sphere $S^n$ is also coverable with two maps, since just like $S^2$ removing a single point yields a space homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Stereographic projection easily generalizes to $n$ dimensions here.

Comment: @user1952009 As for a torus (represented as an $n$-cube with opposite sides identified), it takes minimum $3$ maps for $T^2$, since the remaining uncovered surface after one map is homotopic to a bouquet of 2 circles, which can't be mapped onto $\Bbb R^2$ without changing the order of the lines coming in to the common vertex. It's hard to explain the geometry and harder to state rigorously, but I would bet good money that it takes $n+1$ maps to cover $T^n$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The least you can do is 2 parametrizations. One such way of doing this is by the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection), in which a pole of the sphere is removed, and then the rest of the sphere is projected to the plane. Then the same is done by removing the opposite pole.

Comment: The sphere being compact, it cannot be covered by a single chart! Now the demonstration is complete.